# Python - throw exception if division has remainder?

Tags: python

In Python, you can do:

```
assert a % b == 0
c = a // b
```

Is there a shorthand for this?  In other words, a way to do integer division that throws an exception if there is a remainder?

The reason I ask is that it would be convenient in situations like this:

```
count = len(self.rawr.foo) / self.this.is.a.long.variable
```

Right now I have to make temporary variables:

```
a = len(self.rawr.foo)
b = self.this.is.a.long.variable
assert a % b == 0
count = a // b
```

which does not seem very pythonic.

I know that some languages like C# have ways to do safe division; strange that Python doesn't.

Comment: You may want to be more explicit about `assert`, such as raising an exception explicitly. At least, keep in mind that `python -O` causes `assert` statements to be ignored (among other things).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
count, rem = divmod(len(self.rawr.foo), self.this.is.a.long.variable)
assert not rem # or `assert rem == 0`
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Despite it being built-in, I never knew about divmod.  Thanks.